# How to access shifts of a team? "Sorry, the team was not found, or you may not have access to it"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I would like to read a team's shifts using [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).
However i always fail with different errors and get contradicting server messages.

I send the API requests with Postman.
I am using Application authorization method. I think i have set all required Api permissions for my app.

I beleive i supply the correct headers, like:

1. Authorization
2. Content-Type
3. MS-APP-ACTS-AS

When i send the request like this to GET a team:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}
```

i get the following error message:

```
"error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "No team found with Group Id {id}",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-09-05T08:37:17",
        "request-id": "id"
    }
}
```

But when i try to create the team (from a group) like this:

```
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/team
```

I get the error as follows:

```
"error": {
    "code": "Conflict",
    "message": "Team already exists",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-09-05T08:33:33",
        "request-id": "id"
    }
}
```

When i try to make my actual call of interest, like:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/schedule/shifts
```

That also fails with error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"NotFound\",\"message\":\"Sorry, the team was not found, or you may not have access to it.\",\"details\":[],\"innererror\":{\"code\":\"TeamNotFound\"}}}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-05T08:59:55",
            "request-id": "id"
        }
    }
}
```

Pleaset help me understand what i am doing wrong!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: maybe you need to add authorization header when login  or accessibility is required!

Comment: I think i prvovide the correct headers. Please see the edited part.

Comment: Please enable the schedule for the group first by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-schedule?view=graph-rest-1.0#request). Then try to get the shifts.

Comment: Hello, thx for the answer. When i try this request to enable the schedule, i got an answer with code 204 No Content, hence nothing in the answer body. I did this before, i tought it is not a problem. Now i see when i create a team, the scedule's provisionStatus is "notStarted". After i try to enable the schedule, the provisionStatus changes to"failed" with GraphResourceNotFound. When i try to list the teams as [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-list-all-teams?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) i got all the teams. So i have no idea wath resource is not found.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. Will it help if i try delegated authentication? I just suppose there must be a problems when creating a team, becuase when I filter for it by ID, i have no results, but when i try to create it, i face the message "Team already exists"...  Or something wrong with schedule provisionig but i don't know how to influance it. I just read al the docs already and tried all an all sequential order (except delegated authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Solved (itself).

So what was happening:

1. i created a team ([directly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0) or from a [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)).
2. [created a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-schedule?view=graph-rest-1.0) for the team.
3. get the schedule for the team, and see the response:

```
"enabled": false,
"provisionStatus": "Failed", (so not running or queuing or something)
"provisionStatusCode": "GraphResourceNotFound",
```

4. struggle few (like 4-5) days
5. without changing a thing, get the schedule showing:

```
"enabled": true,
"provisionStatus": "Completed",
"provisionStatusCode": null,
```

Maybe it would help others to see the possible wait time length or add a clarification about the **provisionStatus** field’s status progression.